# from php url to json with angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I am pretty much new to angularjs and onsenUI and have been stuck on figuring out how to display data from the php url into my page...

here is my code

controller.js

```
angular.module('app').controller('CardController',['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://sth.sth.sth.php')
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.cards = data.cards;

      })
      .error(function(error, status, headers, config) {
         console.log(error);
         console.log("Error occured");
      });
```

card.html

```
<div ng-controller="CardController">
    <ul >
        <li ng-repeat="item in cards track by $index">
          {{cards.title}}
          {{cards.id}}
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

I will be more than thankful if someone chip me a way to figure it out. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `cards` its should be `item` -

```
    <li ng-repeat="item in cards track by $index">
      {{item.title}}
      {{item.id}}
    </li>
```

Comment: still its giving me this error... don't really have a token error, but it states that I do... SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( at Object.parse (native) at fromJson (localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:1250:14) at defaultHttpResponseTransform

Comment: @boochoo `console.log(data)` from the server and check if its a valid JSON